# Java reflection: create a instance using params from a treemap like python

Tags: java, python, reflection

I am a python dev , now i want to create a Java instance using params from a treemap just like create a python instance which params from a dict...i try to do it through java reflection. but i can't find the solution.

anybody can give me a hand? THX

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am following, but from what I understand - you are trying to create properties of the object on the fly.

Well, that cannot be done in java, partially because the language is [statically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) [unlike python].

In java, all **fields of the object must be created at compile time**. Reflection can help you to manipulate objects, but not to change their structure completely.

A **workaround** could be to use a [`Map<String,Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and hold the properites there. You will not need reflection for using this solution [which is a good thing, since reflection is both unsafe and tends to [slow-down overall performance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) of the program].

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for!
Create a map to keep your classes.

```
private static Map<String, Class<? extends MySuperClass>> classesMap = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends MySuperClass>>();
```

Put class objects in map

```
static {
      classesMap.put("PERSON_CLASS", Person.class); 
      classesMap.put("ADDRESS_CLASS", Address.class);
}
```

Then a getInstance method that returns the instance of given class.

```
private static MySuperClass getInstance(String classNameConstant) throws Exception{
     Class<? extends MySuperClass> myClass = classesMap.get(classNameConstant);
     if(myClass!=null){
        return myClass.newInstance();
     }
     return null;
}
```

Hope this helps. Note: I don't know python.